# How to connect to local PostGIS (PostgreS) database using Docker compose in Django project?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgis

I need to connect to existing db in my computer. When I create db service with postgis image, it creates a new database inside docker container. But I need to connect to my local one. Is it possible?
*docker-compose.yml* :

```
  version: '3'
  services:
      build: ./
      command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --i rest_framework && gunicorn orion-amr.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=2"
      ports:
        - "${webport}:8000"
      env_file:
        - ./.env
```

*settings.py* :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('pgdatabase'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('pguser'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('pgpassword'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('pghostname'),
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

*.env* file:

```
pgport=5432
webport=8000
SECRET_KEY=z)mf(y#w7-_8y1)0(v*n@w@lzf)!0=g_rj5$%1w6g-t!7nbk05
pgdatabase=amr_or
pgpassword=root
pghostname=localhost
pguser=postgres
DEBUG=
```

Now I have this error:

```
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 0):

> I really hope you did not expose your real `SECRET_KEY` to the rest of the internet. Don't forget to change it if you did.

If I remember correctly (based on a question you asked earlier this year), you are running Docker for Windows. Take a look at the [docs over here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds), it says

> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name `host.docker.internal`, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Windows.

Hence, set `pghostname` to `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`.

Since you state, that you "need to connect to existing db in (your) computer", I will go ahead and assume you do this for development purposes, so this should suffice.

On production, however, you will need to run the database in a separate container and map the volumes.

Comment: Ah, now I see this is a duplicate question... Please, try not to create duplicate questions or at least delete the old one if you're going to recreate it...